# The meaning of "21 Guns" in Greenday's song

Tags: phrase-meaning

I have heard a song by Greenday.
It is "21 guns"; their best song.
I really don't know the meaning of "21 guns".
Please explain this meaning to me.

Answer (score 2):

A "21 gun salute" is a traditional part of very formal American military funerals.

It is not clear from the lyrics whether the characters are "giving up the fight" to avoid being killed, or because they have been killed.  The music video might make clear which meaning(s) were intended.

In many battles, more men are shot in the back while trying to run away, than are killed fighting bravely.  Thus, it is possible that the characters both "gave up the fight" to try to avoid being killed, and "gave up the fight" because they were killed.

Answer (score 0):

It’s a legendary song of Green Day. The song is about to accept the end of something and accept your defeat. The Album that this song comes from, 21st Century Breakdown, is similar to the rock opera style that Green Day tried with American idiot. By the way 21 guns is a salute for someone that is fallen.21 Guns" is a protest song, protesting war. This song is an anti-war song which targets world peace. Although this song doesn't protest a specific war, it protests war in general.However, at most military funerals what many mistake for a 21-gun salute is actually an honor guard team firing three volleys from rifles.